# Separate onClick for the component as a whole and a button within the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am in the process of creating a todo list written in React. I have a functional component `ListItem` which renders an `<li>` element with the task and a trash button.

My current functionality: When the user clicks on the actual text, the text gets struck out, and when they click on the trash button the ListItem gets deleted.

```
function ListItem(props) {
  return (
    <li class="list-item"}>
      <span class="item-name font" onClick={props.handleItem}>
        {props.value}
      </span>
      <button id="trash-button" onClick={props.handleTrash}>
        Trash
      </button>
    </li>
  );
}
```

What I want my functionality to be: When the user clicks anywhere in the `<li>` item (**excluding the trash button**) the text is struck out, and when they click on the trash button the ListItem gets deleted.

I thought I could achieve the above by shifting the `handleItem` `onClick` to the `<li>` item.

```
function ListItem(props) {
  return (
    <li class="list-item" onClick={props.handleItem}>
      <span class="item-name font">
        {props.value}
      </span>
      <button id="trash-button" onClick={props.handleTrash}>
        Trash
      </button>
    </li>
  );
}
```

However what ends up happening is that even when the trash button is clicked, the `handleItem` function gets called along with the `handleTrash` function. Is there a way I can suppress the `handleItem` function when `handleTrash` is called?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: My entire code for the Todo List. The form that takes in the task is called `AddEntry` and that's separate from everything else so I'm not including it.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import AddEntry from './AddEntry'

function ListItem(props) {
  return (
    <li class="list-item" onClick={props.handleItem}>
      <span class="item-name font">
        {props.value}
      </span>
      <button id="trash-button" onClick={props.handleTrash}>
        Trash
      </button>
    </li>
  );
}


class TodoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      entries: []
    };

    this.handleItem = this.handleItem.bind(this);
    this.handleTrash = this.handleTrash.bind(this);
    this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
  }

  renderListItem(e) {
    if(e.struck) {
      return (
        <ListItem
          key={e.key}
          value={<strike>{e.item}</strike>}
          handleTrash={() => this.handleTrash(e)}
          handleItem={() => this.handleItem(e)}
        />
      );
    }

    else {
     return(
      <ListItem
          key={e.key}
          value={e.item}
          handleTrash={() => this.handleTrash(e)}
          handleItem={() => this.handleItem(e)}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  handleAdd(e) {
    const entries = this.state.entries;
    entries.push({item: e, struck: false, key: entries.length});
    this.setState({
      entries: entries
    });
  }

  handleTrash(e) {
    const entries = this.state.entries;
    for(let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
      if(entries[i] === e) {
        entries.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }

    this.setState({
      entries: entries
    });
  }

  handleItem(e) {
    console.log("hi");
    const entries = this.state.entries;
    let index = entries.findIndex(ele => e.key === ele.key);
    entries[index].struck = !entries[index].struck;
    this.setState({
      entries: entries
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="todo-list">
          <AddEntry handleAdd={this.handleAdd}/>
          <ul>{this.state.entries.map((e) => this.renderListItem(e))}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

}


ReactDOM.render(
  <TodoList />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[this is how it's working with the onClick in the li element](https://puu.sh/AEoen/e01fe9ce1d.mov)

Comment: just remove the `onClick` from the trash then. Or change css of your span item. It is hard to figure out what exactly you mean by anywhere in the li item. Post the actual visuals.

Comment: Also post the `handleTrash` function itself.

Comment: You can make your `li` such that, there are two things in your `li`. One: all other things except your trash button (inside a div), other: your trash button. And put your `onClick` logic for that `div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep the onClick on `li` itself and in your `handleTrash` function use `preventPropogation` to stop propogation.

```
 handleTrash(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   // code the rest
}
```

here is a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/1vqwo4j0yl